# Tables of C++ member functions

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, pointer-to-member

I need a table that maps codes to C++ member functions. Suppose we have this class:

```
class foo
{
  bool one() const;
  bool two() const;
  bool call(char*) const;
};
```

What I want is a table like this:

```
{
  { “somestring”,  one },
  { ”otherstring”, two }
};
```

So that if I have a `foo` object `f`, `f.call(”somestring”)` would look up “somestring” in the table, call the `one()` member function, and return the result.

All of the called functions have identical prototypes, i.e., they are const, take no parameters, and return bool.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: This is all very doable by hand. a more interesting question is what is the best way to do automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only need to store members of the same class, with the same arguments and return types, you can use pointer-to-member-functions:

```
bool foo::call(char const * name) const {
    static std::map<std::string, bool (foo::*)() const> table 
    {
        {"one", &foo::one}, 
        {"two", &foo::two}
    };

    auto entry = table.find(name);
    if (entry != table.end()) {
        return (this->*(entry->second))();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That uses the new initialisation syntax of C++11. If your compiler doesn't support it, there are various other options. You could initialise the map with a static function:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, bool (foo::*)() const> table_type;
static table_type table = make_table();

static table_type make_table() {
    table_type table;
    table["one"] = &foo::one;
    table["two"] = &foo::two;
    return table;
}
```

or you could use [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html):

```
static std::map<std::string, bool (foo::*)() const> table = 
    boost::assign::map_list_of
        ("one", &foo::one)
        ("two", &foo::two);
```

or you could use an array, and find the entry with `std::find_if` (or a simple `for` loop if your library doesn't have that yet), or `std::binary_search` if you make sure the array is sorted.

Comment: +1 for using `auto`. Otherwise one have to write `std::map<std::string, bool (foo::*)() const>::iterator` which is too ugly!

Comment: I like the elegance and simplicity of this method, but I didn't think it was possible to initialize a `map` like that? MSVC doesn't like it, anyway.

Comment: @chrisd: That's the new C++11 initialisation syntax. I've added a few alternatives if your compiler doesn't support it.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I had already implemented this by initializing the map from a table similar to the one shown by Nawaz below, but I was trying to understand your original syntax. I guess it's time to look into C++11. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible, using **pointer to member** syntax.

Using the prototypes you supplied, the map would be.

```
std::map< std::string, bool( foo::*)() const>
```

It would be called with this syntax

```
this->*my_map["somestring"]();
```

That odd-looking `->*` operator is for pointer to member functions, which can have some odd considerations, due to inheritance.  (It's not just a raw address, as `->` would expect)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks.  I overlooked that `const`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
struct foo_method
{
   std::string name;
   bool (foo::*pfun)() const;
};

foo_method methodTable[] = 
{
  { “somestring”,  &foo::one },
  { ”otherstring”, &foo::one }
};

void foo::call(const char* name) const
{
   size_t size = sizeof(methodTable)/sizeof(*methodTable);
   for(size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
   {
       if ( methodTable[i].name == name )
       {
           bool (foo::*pfun)() const = methodTable[i].pfun;
           (this->*pfun)(); //invoke
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think I'd prefer a map to a table, but the idea is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with `boost::function` with `std::map`. Concretely, something like this :

```
typedef boost::function<bool()> MyFunc;
typedef std::map<std::string, MyFunc> MyFuncMap;
```

Then, given an instance of MyFuncMap, you could just do `map["something"]()`. Then you could wrap that in a class that overloads `operator()`. You could use function pointers/references, but I prefer using `boost::function` because it allows me to bind pointers to member functions (using boost::bind) or use other function objects. You can also test `boost::function` in conditionals as you would with regular function pointers.

Here is the relevant documentation :

- [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/function.html)
- [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bind/bind.html)

Good luck!

Edit: Regarding your question about the const member and `boost::function`, here's an example :

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

typedef boost::function<bool ()> FuncPtr;

struct Test
{
    bool test() const
    {
        std::cout << "yay" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Test t;
    FuncPtr ptr = boost::bind(&Test::test, &t);
    ptr();
}
```

Comment: `const` is part of the function's type, but I don't know how that interacts with `boost::function`.  Should it be part of the declaration?

Comment: Just looked into it, it seems that `boost::function<bool ()>` will do for both const and non-const members. Not quite sure how or why, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add that a pointer to a member function is meaningless without having an instance of a class on which to call it. The situation you've described accounts for this (and I think you know this), however in other situations, it may be necessary to encapsulate the function pointer with a pointer or reference to the instance to which it corresponds in some sort of [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) construct.